# Why do we get increase in BER with increase in Eb/N0 of the signal?

Tags: noise, communication, wireless, digital-communications, modulation

I'm working on a problem of MSK modulation scheme. I have passed my modulated signal through SUI channel Models and AWGN.
But As I want to do analysis on the performance of SUI channels I'm getting Higher BER at Higher Eb/N0 and less BER at Less Eb/N0.
Why is that?

[image: This is the output i'm getting...Sometimes it works for some channels but for some channnels the BER increases with increase in Eb/N0]

```matlab
clc
clear all
close all

stream_length = 6000;
bit_stream = randi([0, 1], 1, stream_length);
frequency = 10;
Tb = 1;
Eb = 1;

% SUI Channel Modeling
SUI_indx_range = 1:6; % Consider all SUI channels
direct = 1; % 0 for omni, 1 for directional
fs = 1; % Replace with your actual sampling rate in MHz

% Eb/N0 values for analysis
EbN0_dB_range = -25:5:5;

% Initialize arrays to store BER values
BER_simulation = zeros(length(SUI_indx_range), length(EbN0_dB_range));

for sui_idx = 1:length(SUI_indx_range)
    SUI_indx = SUI_indx_range(sui_idx);

    % Generate MSK modulated signal
    modulated_signal = msk_mod(bit_stream, frequency, Tb, Eb);

    % Pass through the SUI channel
    [out, ~] = SUI_model(modulated_signal, SUI_indx, direct, fs);

    % Print SUI Channel Information
    fprintf('SUI Channel %d:\n', SUI_indx);

    % Analyze BER vs Eb/N0 for each signal
    for eb_n0_idx = 1:length(EbN0_dB_range)
        EbN0_dB = EbN0_dB_range(eb_n0_idx);

        % Add AWGN to the received signal from SUI channel
        received_signal_with_noise = awgn(out, EbN0_dB, 'measured');

        % Demodulate the signal with noise
        demodulated_bits = msk_demod(received_signal_with_noise, frequency, Tb);

        % Calculate BER
        error_bits = sum(xor(demodulated_bits, bit_stream));
        BER_simulation(sui_idx, eb_n0_idx) = error_bits / length(bit_stream);

        % Print BER values
        fprintf('Eb/N0 = %2d dB: BER = %.6f\n', EbN0_dB, BER_simulation(sui_idx, eb_n0_idx));
    end

    % Plot BER vs Eb/N0 for each signal
    figure;
    plot(EbN0_dB_range, BER_simulation(sui_idx, :), 'LineWidth', 2, 'DisplayName', ['SUI ' num2str(SUI_indx)]);
    grid on;
    xlabel('Eb/N0 (dB)');
    ylabel('Bit Error Rate (BER)');
    title(['BER vs Eb/N0 for MSK through SUI Channel ' num2str(SUI_indx)]);
    legend('show');
end


function [out,imp] =SUI_model(dat,SUI_indx, direct, fs )

% check for input parameter range
if ~ismember(direct,[0,1])
error('direct must be in the range [0,1]' );
end;
if ~ismember(SUI_indx,[1:6])
error('direct must be in the range 1:6' );
end;
%model information matrix
SUI1_omni=[... %SU1 omni model
0 0.4 0.8; ... %tap delay in uSe
0 -15 -20;... %relative power
4 0 0 ]; %K factor per tap
SUI1_dir=[... %SU1 deirectional 30deg model
0 0.4 0.8; ...
0 -21 -32;...
16 0 0 ];
SUI2_omni=[... %SU2 omni model
0 0.5 1.0; ...
0 -12 -15;...
2 0 0 ];
SUI2_dir=[... %SU2 omni model
0 0.5 1.0; ...
0 -18 -27;...
8 0 0 ];
SUI3_omni=[... %SU3 omni model
0 0.5 1.0; ...
0 -5 -10;...
1 0 0 ];
SUI3_dir=[... %SU3 dir model
0 0.5 1.0; ...
0 -11 -22;...
3 0 0 ];
SUI4_omni=[... %SU4 omni model
0 2 4; ...
0 -4 -8;...
0 0 0 ];
SUI4_dir=[... %SU4 dir model
0 2 4; ...
0 -10 -20;...
0 0 0 ];
SUI5_omni=[... %SU5 omni model
0 4 10; ...
0 -5 -10;...
0 0 0 ];
SUI5_dir=[... %SU5 dir model
0 4 10; ...
0 -11 -22;...
0 0 0 ];
SUI6_omni=[... %SU6 omni model
0 14 20; ...
0 -10 -20;...
0 0 0 ];
SUI6_dir=[... %SU6 dir model
0 14 20; ...
0 -16 -26;...
0 0 0 ];
%overall SUI model
SUI={SUI1_omni SUI2_omni SUI3_omni SUI4_omni SUI5_omni SUI6_omni ;...
SUI1_dir SUI2_dir SUI3_dir SUI4_dir SUI5_dir SUI6_dir};
%select a specific model
SUI_mod=SUI{direct+1,SUI_indx};

%number of taps
n=size(SUI_mod,2);
%location of taps
locs=1+round(SUI_mod(1,:)*fs);
imp=zeros(1,max(locs));
%get taps
taps=gen_rice(10.^(SUI_mod(3,:)/10)... %power of taps
,SUI_mod(2,:),... %K factor of taps
1); %normalize the result
imp(locs)=taps;
out = filter(imp,1,dat);
end
```

This code is taken only for the purpose of analysis.

Comment: In effect you are asking for your code to be debugged? Also, in effect, you haven't analysed the results in detail on a bit-by-bit basis on a snippet of data that contains an error?